# R: Plot flexsurvspline object and color by group

Tags: r

I am using flexsurvspline to analyse time to event for patient data, for five different age groups.  Is it possible to colour the five different regression lines by age group, to enable identification of the groups?
The only thing that I have managed is to color the observations, using a vector that contains different colors, and this would be sufficient however my problem is that I do not know how to set the order and thereby the coloring of the groups, so that I know which age group belongs to which curve. 
From running summary(spline) I know that there is an increased hazard for older age groups, but the coloring of the age groups does not agree, and this is because I do not know how to order them I think.

I do the following:

## Assigning age Groups

```
dia$agecat[dia$age2 > 29 & dia$age2 <= 49] <- "30-49"
dia$agecat[dia$age2 > 49 & dia$age2 <= 59] <- "50-59"
dia$agecat[dia$age2 > 59 & dia$age2 <= 69] <- "60-69"
dia$agecat[dia$age2 > 69 & dia$age2 <= 79] <- "70-79"
dia$agecat[dia$age2 > 79] <- "80+"
dia$agecat2 <- as.factor(dia$agecat)
```

## Running the spline function

```
diaspline25 <- flexsurvspline(Surv(months_to_event, censor) ~ agecat2, data=dia, knots=c(log50), log(100), log(150), log(200), log(250)), scale="hazard")
```

## Making color vector

```
cols <- divPalette(n=5, name= "RdYlBu")
dia$col[dia$agecat2=="30-49"] <- cols[1]
dia$col[dia$agecat2=="50-59"] <- cols[2]
dia$col[dia$agecat2=="60-69"] <- cols[3]
dia$col[dia$agecat2=="70-79"] <-  cols[4]
dia$col[dia$agecat2=="80+"] <- cols[5]
ages <- c("30-49", "50-59", "60-69", "70-79", "80+")
```

## Plotting

```
plot(diaspline25, ci=TRUE, lwd=3, lwd.ci=1, col.obs=cols, col = "black", col.ci="grey", xlab="Months from diagnosis", ylab="Proportion")
legend("bottomleft", legend=ages, col = cols, pch=19, cex = 1, title = "Age category")
```

As you may have noticed I am not actually using dia$col to color the observations, because that just gives the groups the first five colors in the vector, not unique colors.
Also, it is not possible to pass a color vector to “col = “,  it just plots the first color in the vector for all five lines anyway.

Is there some way to differentiate the groups by color, and knowing what color belongs to what groups? Of course I could hard code the colors based on the output from summary(), but there is probably a better way? I would be so grateful if you could give me some advice!

Thank you in advance!